# ITextRenderer - TextBox out of generated Pdf mediabox

Tags: html, pdf, converters, flying-saucer

I'm trying to convert a html content document to pdf using ITextRenderer using this version of library:

```
implementation group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf-itext5', version: '9.1.22'
```

This is what I'm doing to convert my html to pdf:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(getXHTMLFromHTML(out.toString()));
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(byteArrayOutputStream);
```

However I'm getting a problem with a specific part of my html, a table that's supposed to be a list. This is the result in adobe acrobat:

[image]

As you can see the text box is out of the mediabox of the pdf, there's no cropbox present, and the result is that text is not fully visible.

Here is the html that causes this issue:

```
<div id="4a9dc6ae-3d2e-448b-8e70-3422659f87bd" class="alinea">
    <p>Ne sont pas déductibles les dépenses suivantes:</p>
    <table id="9c582e44-1932-4bee-b93e-6fb75b725f4b" style="width: 1127px;" class="custom-list">
        <tbody class="body number-style dot-separator">
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">1.</td>
            <td class="cell">les dépenses faites en vue de remplir des obligations imposées �&nbsp; la collectivité par ses statuts ou son pacte social;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">2.</td>
            <td class="cell">l'impôt sur le revenu des collectivités, l'impôt sur la fortune et l'impôt commercial communal;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">3.</td>
            <td class="cell">les rémunérations imposables en vertu du premier alinéa, numéro 2 de l'<a id="e48d16e9-3eeb-4d99-91c3-f97b8d206a5e" href="https://00f74ba44b4a6fc879f193e8a262c50fb07e0f7d81-apidata.googleusercontent.com/#/o/link/1/a0ea877e-3736-4ce9-b09f-fc1be79b787a" class="tech_content LINK_INTERN">article 91</a>;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="cell">4.</td>
            <td class="cell">les dépenses faites dans un but cultuel, charitable ou d'intérêt général sans préjudice de la disposition prévue au premier alinéa, numéro 3 de l'<a id="3e74194c-2ae3-4b41-9efc-c6a1c23102cb" href="https://00f74ba44b4a6fc879f193e8a262c50fb07e0f7d81-apidata.googleusercontent.com/#/o/link/1/a0eb1cc1-3e9c-4175-9a52-be2d0b6cc455" class="tech_content LINK_INTERN">article 109;</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5.</td>
            <td>les intérêts ou redevances dus lorsque les conditions suivantes sont simultanément remplies :
                <table class="custom-list" id="02812a11-d2d0-92cb-9c78-e9fa30f8fa1d" style="width: 955px;">
                    <tbody class="body lower-alpha-style one-bracket-separator">
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="cell">a)</td>
                        <td class="cell">le bénéficiaire des intérêts ou redevances est un organisme �&nbsp; caractère collectif au sens de l’article 159. Si le bénéficiaire n’est pas le bénéficiaire effectif, il y a lieu de prendre en considération le bénéficiaire effectif ;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="cell">b)</td>
                        <td class="cell">l’organisme �&nbsp; caractère collectif qui est le bénéficiaire des intérêts ou redevances est une entreprise liée au sens de l’article 56 ;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="cell">c)</td>
                        <td class="cell">l’organisme �&nbsp; caractère collectif qui est le bénéficiaire des intérêts ou redevances est établi dans un pays ou territoire figurant �&nbsp; l’annexe I des conclusions du Conseil de l’Union européenne relatives �&nbsp; la liste révisée de l’Union européenne des pays et territoires non coopératifs �&nbsp; des fins fiscales (ci-après «&nbsp;annexe I&nbsp;»), dans les conditions spécifiées ci-après.</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table><p></p><p>Toutefois, la disposition du présent numéro n’est pas applicable si le contribuable apporte la preuve que l’opération �&nbsp; laquelle correspondent les intérêts ou redevances dus est utilisée pour des motifs commerciaux valables qui reflètent la réalité économique.</p><p></p><p>Le terme « intérêts » employé dans le présent numéro désigne les intérêts et arrérages dus qui se rapportent �&nbsp; des créances de toute nature, assorties ou non de garanties hypothécaires ou d’une clause de participation aux bénéfices du débiteur, et notamment les intérêts et arrérages d’obligations d’emprunts, y compris les primes et lots attachés �&nbsp; ces titres. Les pénalisations pour paiement tardif ne sont pas considérées comme des intérêts au sens du présent numéro.</p><p></p><p>Le terme « redevances » employé dans le présent numéro désigne les rémunérations de toute nature dues pour l’usage ou la concession de l’usage d’un droit d’auteur sur une œuvre littéraire, artistique ou scientifique, y compris les films cinématographiques, d’un brevet, d’une marque de fabrique ou de commerce, d’un dessin ou d’un modèle, d’un plan, d’une formule ou d’un procédé secrets et pourdes informations ayant trait �&nbsp; une expérience acquise dans le domaine industriel, commercial ou scientifique.</p><p></p><p>À partir du 1er mars 2021, la disposition du présent numéro s’applique concernant les pays et territoires qui figurent �&nbsp; l’annexe I, dans sa dernière version, telle que publiée au Journal officiel de l’Union européenne �&nbsp; cette date. À partir du 1er janvier de chaque année qui suit, elle s’applique concernant les pays et territoires qui figurent �&nbsp; l’annexe I, dans sa dernière version au 1er janvier de l’année subséquente en question, telle que publiée au Journal officiel de l’Union européenne �&nbsp; cette date.</p><p></p><p>Toutefois, lorsque des pays et territoires ne figurent plus �&nbsp; l’annexe I, dans sa dernière version au 1er janvier d’une année subséquente, telle que publiée au Journal officiel de l’Union européenne �&nbsp; cette date, la disposition du présent numéro cesse de s’appliquer concernant ces pays et territoires dès la date de publication au Journal officiel de l’Union européenne de l’annexe I dans sa dernière version mentionnée ci-avant. En cas de version antérieure de l’annexe I au cours de la même année opérant pour la première fois le retrait du pays ou territoire en question, la disposition du présent numéro cesse de s’appliquer déj�&nbsp; dès la date de publication au Journal officiel de l’Union européenne de l’annexe I, dans une telle version antérieure opérant le retrait du pays ou territoire en question.</p></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for help, I have look everywhere but I don't see anybody having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that itext wraps the content of a table inside the margins of the pdf only if the table (or any element) does not provide a fixed width or height. So the solution for me in this case was to remove the width and height from my html table.